# Is there a "latch" node in animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

I need a Boolean node that does the following. If the input is true at any time, the output becomes true and stays true. Even if the input is removed or becomes false, the output must stay true. It's like detecting a pulse or touching a button then walking away and the bulb doesn't turn off when you walk away.

By nature, the node should have another input to turn it off.

Is there a node that does that in animation nodes? If no, Is there an easy workaround?

Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom property on an object to do it :

Create a new empty and set your node tree like so :

[image]

Now when you toggle the boolean input, the custom property is updated and persists between frames.

[image]

Now there may be more efficient ways to rig it but your latch logic boils down to :

[image]

In action :

[image]